# Merging two datasets only by first row in R

Tags: r, merge

I need to merge two datasets, but in the second one, there can be duplicate id, for example several id of 1,1,1. If there are duplicate id, how to merge to the very first row of them?

To be more clear, here's a reproducible example:

```
df1
structure(list(id = 1:2, y = 10:11), .Names = c("id", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), x1 = 435:438, x2 = c(435L, 
436L, 436L, 438L), x3 = c(435L, 436L, 436L, 438L)), .Names = c("id", 
"x1", "x2", "x3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Eaxample: In output i expect this format

```
id  y   x1  x2  x3
1   10  435 435 435
2   11  438 438 438
```

I.E.   2 and 3 rows (1 id) do not participate in  merging.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `data.table`. You can retain only first occurrence where `id == 1` from your second data set and then `merge` both the data sets.

Here is the solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)
df2[, idx := 1:.N, by = id]
df2 <- df2[idx == 1, ]
df2[, idx := NULL]
output <- merge(df1, df2, by = "id")
output
```

It'll give you your desired output:

```
 id  y  x1  x2  x3
1  1 10 435 435 435
2  2 11 438 438 438
```